# How can I edit a specific cell in the average column of an existing cross-tab report in IBM Cognos Analytics?

Tags: cognos

I am currently working on modifying a cross-tab report in IBM Cognos Analytics, and I'm facing difficulties in editing a specific cell within the average column. The requirement is to replace the existing calculation in that cell with my own custom calculation. Unfortunately, I am unsure of the steps involved in accomplishing this task.

Could someone please guide me on how to edit a particular cell within the average column of a cross-tab report in IBM Cognos Analytics? Specifically, I would like to know:

The procedure for identifying and selecting the specific cell in the average column.
The steps to modify the calculation in the selected cell with my custom calculation.

I don't have any screenshot to share from cognos as its in restricted environment but below is scenario that I have created in excel. Highlighted in orange color is what i am getting and highlighted in yellow is what I actually require so no of weeks can increase or decrease according to my prompts and i need to divide the production count  by the distinct number count of weeks. this is required in only one cell of production hrs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPlwR.png)

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to to query calculation but cognos wont just take it give me error it wont run my report.

Comment: It's a lot less work for those who may provide you an answer if you include numbers a text rather than an image, and if you provide a sample report spec using the GO Sales (query) package that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a specific cell, but you can create a calculation that will average within the context of the entire report rather than just that one row header.  Drag a Query Calculation to the right side of the `Total` column label.  The data item expression will look something like this:

```
total([namespace].[query subject1].[hours]) / count([namespace].[query subject2].[week] for report)
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer let me check this and i will confirm you back. Thanks for your help